# How do the laws of physics work in quantum system?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, universe

If I throw a stone in the air,how does earth know that it(stone) needs to be pulled. My point is are the rules of physics contained inside every single particle? Or is there a central body checking the conditions every single frame and then doing the respective actions?(here frame means periodic update of the universe just like in computer graphics). My question is kind of silly, but I hope that there is answer somewhere.

Comment: The answer to "how does the universe calculate things" is "we have no idea".

Comment: A stone is not only pulled when it is in the air. Also, at a very fundamental level, physics does not ask why the laws of physics are what they are, but only what the laws of physics are. Also, the most fundamental laws of physics should be the same everywhere. If that wouldn't be the case for some law, we would expect the existence of some principle explaining the origin of the local differences, which would, in turn, be universal.

Comment: You don’t need any QM to describe a stone thrown in the air, so why are you asking about a “quantum system” and why did you add the tag “quantum-mechanics”?

Comment: "Is there a central body checking the conditions every single frame and then doing the respective actions"  - IIRC He used to be called "God".

Comment: GR says that the stone is moving at constant velocity (through curved spacetime). Does it need help to do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there an equivalent of computation of physical processes in nature?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/570845/)